# Date format of bootstrap 4 got changed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 4 date type

`<input type="date" class="form-control" id="add-stud-basicInfo-dob">`

In UI its is showing (Date formate dd-mm-yyyy)

[image]

but when I am  entering the value, it looks like this

[image]

That is fine but when I am retrieving the value then I am getting

"dob":"1990-07-04" (which is in the formate of yyyy-mm-dd as the date formate got changed)

but I want the value in dd-mm-yyyy formate only .

How to override this default.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap datepicker ?

Comment: yes , we are using bootstrap 4 "https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP Post method always return your date to : yyyy-mm-dd. If you want dd-mm-yyyy use the function :

```
date('m-d-Y', strtotime($_POST['date']))
```